# Remove virtual keyboard from start up

Tags: windows-7, login, login-screen, on-screen-keyboard

When even I log into by Windows 7 PC the virtual keyboard starts up **how can I disable this?**

I deselected "On-Screen keyboard" from the **Ease of Access** selection found in the login screen.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this and let me know if this works ?

In Windows 7 just go to "Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Ease of Access Center -> Use the computer without a mouse or keyboard" and uncheck the  "Use On-Screen Keyboard" option and click Ok.
Then, on the left panel there's the "Change administrative settings" options. Click it and check the "Apply all settings to the logon desktop" and press Apply.

Open it up and go to the Ease of Access section. Under Explore all settings, click on Use the computer without a mouse or keyboard:
[image]

Now uncheck the Use On-Screen Keyboard check-box under Type using a pointing device:
[image]

Comment: Nice , glad it worked for you :)